# Omit type for dynamic property without modifying class?

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a bunch of domain objects that I serialize, send to other applications and then deserialize using `Json.Net`. These objects may have properties that are

- Defined as an abstract base class with multiple derived classes
- Dynamic Properties

I've used `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, which adds the `$type` property to types that differ from the declared type. However, this setting has an unwanted side effect on my dynamic properties, namely that the types of them gets declared, too.

In the example below `model` is a dynamic property defined as `public dynamic Model { get; set; }` in my C# code.

```
"model":{"$type":"<>f__AnonymousType0`3[[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib],[System.String, mscorlib]], ExampleAssembly","link":"http://www.google.com","name":"John"}
```

When trying to deserialize this string in another assembly, Json.Net can't (of course) find the `ExampleAssembly`. Using the `TypeNameHandling.None` property gives the following property serialization

```
"model": {"link":"http://www.google.com","name":"John"}
```

Which can be successfully deserialized to a `dynamic`. However, this breaks deserialization of derived types.

Any ideas on how to get this to work without implementing custom `IContractResolver` and possibly other custom code?

I don't own the domain objects, so I can't decorate them or their properties with attributes or allow them to implement interfaces etc. What I'm looking for is some sort of setting in the serializer that omits types for `dynamics`.

IMHO this should be configurable through settings somehow, I just havn't found it.

Comment: [JsonIgnore] or Conditional serialization (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm) might be useful

Comment: @Nair: Thanks, but unfortunate not. I do not own the domain object and can't decorate then with attributes or methods. Besides, that does not scale well, as I have to to this for ALL objects.

Comment: Adding `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]` to the relevant property would be the most straightforward way - but in your comment you say you cannot do that.  You might want to [edit] the question to clarify that requirement.

Comment: @dbc besides, I'm not sure that I agree that it is most straight forward, as I would have to (if I was able) to add this property to hundreds of properties (and keep on adding them as new classes was introduced). In my opinion, serialization information belongs to the serializer, not to the objects they serialize.

Comment: If you cannot change your types, then a custom contract resolver looks to be the solution - but your question says you don't want that.

Comment: I just think that I shouldn't need to write my own contract resolver for this, as it feels like this should be the standard behavior for dynamic types (or at least configurable out of the box)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Json.Net does not provide a specific setting to turn off type name handling for dynamic types only.  If you can't (or don't want to) mark the relevant dynamic properties with `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None)]`, then your only other option (short of modifying the Json.Net source code itself) is to implement a custom contract resolver to apply the behavior programmatically.  But don't worry, this is not difficult to do if you derive your resolver from one of the Json.Net-provided resolvers such as `DefaultContractResolver` or `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`.

Here is all the code you would need:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

public class OmitTypeNamesOnDynamicsResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly OmitTypeNamesOnDynamicsResolver Instance = new OmitTypeNamesOnDynamicsResolver();

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.GetCustomAttribute<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute>() != null)
        {
            prop.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then, just add the resolver to the `JsonSerializerSettings` and you should be all set.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    ContractResolver = OmitTypeNamesOnDynamicsResolver.Instance
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
```

Here is a round-trip demo to prove the concept:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo
        {
            Model = new { link = "http://www.google.com", name = "John" },
            Widget1 = new Doodad { Name = "Sprocket", Size = 10 },
            Widget2 = new Thingy { Name = "Coil", Strength = 5 }
        };

        JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            ContractResolver = OmitTypeNamesOnDynamicsResolver.Instance,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine();

        Foo foo2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, settings);
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Model.link);
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Model.name);
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Widget1.Name + " (" + foo2.Widget1.GetType().Name + ")");
        Console.WriteLine(foo2.Widget2.Name + " (" + foo2.Widget2.GetType().Name + ")");
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public dynamic Model { get; set; }
    public AbstractWidget Widget1 { get; set; }
    public AbstractWidget Widget2 { get; set; }
}

public class AbstractWidget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Thingy : AbstractWidget
{
    public int Strength { get; set; }
}

public class Doodad : AbstractWidget
{
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "Model": {
    "link": "http://www.google.com",
    "name": "John"
  },
  "Widget1": {
    "$type": "Doodad, JsonTest",
    "Size": 10,
    "Name": "Sprocket"
  },
  "Widget2": {
    "$type": "Thingy, JsonTest",
    "Strength": 5,
    "Name": "Coil"
  }
}

http://www.google.com
John
Sprocket (Doodad)
Coil (Thingy)
```

Comment: Beautiful! As I said, I'd rather have some out of the box functionality without custom classes. However, your implementation of the Contact Resolver was very small, which is appreciated. Thanks for well written response!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.