# Is it possible to set Json.Net to ignore $type?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Watching [this video on json deserialization attacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLpr-xdpM8wG9g8l21uzfgyx4xAJ9aY7e7&time_continue=349&v=NqHsaVhlxAQ) and it shows this bit of json that can be used to trigger arbitrary code execution on any application that deserializes it.

[image: Using ObjectDataProvider to execute arbitrary code]

Now in my applications, I never even use typed json. I always deserialize to dynamic objects or `JObject`s. I didn't even know about the `$type` property until another unrelated conversation this morning.

Is there a way in my json settings to tell it never to write nor read this property? It's not something I would ever want.

Comment: `"$type"` information is only written when [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) is modified to something other than [`TypeNameHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) -- **which is the default**.  If you never change the value,  `"$type"` information is never omitted.  Similarly `"$type"` properties are ignored on deserialization when `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None`.

Comment: That being said, if a *collection* was serialized by another application using `TypeNameHandling.Arrays` then there will be an extra level of nesting in the JSON.  To strip it when deserializing, see `IgnoreCollectionTypeConverter` from [Strategies for migrating serialized Json.NET document between versions/formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166777/3744182) or `IgnoreArrayTypeConverter` from [make Json.NET ignore $type if it's incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33163163/3744182).

Comment: Finally, if you are working with a 3rd party library that sets `TypeNameHandling` in attributes, you can disable that with a custom contract resolver as shown in [How to disable TypeNameHandling when specified in attributes by using JsonSerializerSettings in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46925930/3744182).

Comment: @dbc imo your comments are exhaustive enough to be the answer!

Comment: For additional examples of security risks when using `TypeNameHandling` see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"$type"` information is only written when [`TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) is modified to something other than [`TypeNameHandling.None`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm) -- **which is the default**.  If you never change the value,  `"$type"` information is never emitted.

Similarly `"$type"` properties are ignored on deserialization when `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None` (which is, again, the default), as is stated in the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm):

```
// for security TypeNameHandling is required when deserializing
Stockholder newStockholder =
  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stockholder>(jsonTypeNameAuto, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
});
```

If nothing in your code (or in class libraries used by your code) ever modifies `TypeNameHandling` to something other than `TypeNameHandling.None` (either via [settings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_TypeNameHandling.htm) or attributes such as [`JsonPropertyAttribute.TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_TypeNameHandling.htm)) then that code execution attack cannot work.  (For more precise details on usages of Json.NET's serializer that are and are not vulnerable to this attack, see [Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf).

Also note that, if you are parsing with [`JToken.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Parse.htm) (or some similar static method like [`JObject.Parse()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm)) rather than deserializing with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>()` then the presence of `"$type"` properties will simply result in such properties getting populated into the `JToken` hierarchy, since `JToken.Parse()` never invokes the serializer. If you nevertheless want to strip those`"$type"` properties after parsing, you can use `JsonExtensions.RemoveTypeMetadata(this JToken root)` from *[Deserialize string that was serialized with TypeNameHandling.All](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803025/3744182)* to do just that.

That being said, if a *collection* was serialized by another application using `TypeNameHandling.Arrays` or `TypeNameHandling.All` then there will be an extra level of nesting in the JSON.  To strip it when deserializing, see `IgnoreCollectionTypeConverter` from *[Strategies for migrating serialized Json.NET document between versions/formats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34166777/3744182)* or `IgnoreArrayTypeConverter` from *[Make Json.NET ignore $type if it's incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33163163/3744182)*.

Finally, if you are working with a 3rd party library that sets `TypeNameHandling` in attributes, you can disable that with a custom contract resolver as shown in *[How to disable TypeNameHandling when specified in attributes by using JsonSerializerSettings in Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46925930/3744182)*.

And if you're really concerned that somebody else in your team might enable `TypeNameHandling`, you could create a custom [`ISerializationBinder`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_ISerializationBinder.htm) that throws an exception whenever an attempt is made to resolve a type or type name:

```
public class DisallowSerializationBindingBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
 #region ISerializationBinder Members

 public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
 {
  throw new JsonSerializationException("Binding of subtypes has been disabled");
 }

 public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
 {
  throw new JsonSerializationException("Binding of subtypes has been disabled");
 }

  #endregion
}
```

Then set it in `JsonSerializerSettings` as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    SerializationBinder = new DisallowSerializationBindingBinder(),
};
```

And modify the settings globally as shown in *[Set default global json serializer settings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21815759/3744182)* (for a console app), *[How to set custom JsonSerializerSettings for Json.NET in MVC 4 Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13274625/3744182)* (for ASP.NET Web API) or *[JsonSerializerSettings and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35772387/3744182)* (for asp.net core).

Comment: I want to have `TypeNameHandling` set to `All`/`Objects`, but I still want to be able to have specific properties/types skipped, so that `$type` is not generated for them.

Comment: @Shimmy - You could start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254872/using-json-net-converters-to-deserialize-properties/6303853#6303853) for specific properties or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39442074/3744182) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996144/typenamehandling-with-attribute-on-a-class/43036371#4303637) for specific types, using `TypeNameHandling.None` in the appropriate place.  You might want to ask another question if you need something specific.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I hope it's going to work.

Comment: I was wondering if I could avoid having to decorate my Json. I am currently deserialising a pretty complex objects and I have to pollute my Jsons with things such as $type: "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ClassName, Namespace]], mscorlib". I am setting TypeNameHandling.All. Not doing those 2 things prevents the deserialisation from working properly. Any tip or pointer would be welcome.

Comment: @progLearner - if you don't want the `$type` properties, you could create custom converters to test the incoming JSON to see which subtype it matches.  See: [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/3744182).

Comment: Very useful @dbc. From you link, what if new GalleryAlbum() needed to be passed an object as argument at construction? Do yo have to create all the nested classes manually?

Comment: @progLearner - you should ask a new question and include a [mcve].  Things can become more complex if your data model uses parameterized constructors.

Comment: @dbc, maybe you can help then. Here is what I am trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67280335/using-custom-contractresolver-or-jsonconverter-to-deserialize-complex-nested-obj?noredirect=1#67280335

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `TypeNameHandling.None` is ignored. But you can use:

```
public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializationSettings
        = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore
};
```